# problem running impalad: libc.so.6 Working in Centos 7 but not in RHEL 7

Tags: c, cmake, cloudera, glibc, impala

As per my understanding Centos 7 and RHEL 7 are similar in terms of version of library in linux. I have development servers running in RHEL7 which has no internet access. That server don't have internet access. So i have to build impala in my local or any other machine where impala is available as impala. As rhel7 and centos 7 has similarity i decided to go with installing centos 7 in my local VMware and build impala there and migrate built impala to rhel7 via scp.

Impala's documentation lake on how to build impala from source. I also lake in knowledge of c and cpp based project development and tools like cmake, configure, make and such.

They have provided one buildall.sh script which automatically builds project. I have built the impala using same. But the same buid is running in Local centos 7 system but not in rhel 7.

Error Message

```
./impalad: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by ./impalad)
./impalad: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by ./impalad)
./impalad: /impala/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by ./impalad)
./impalad: /impala/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1: no version information available (required by ./impalad)
./impalad: /impala/lib64/libssl.so.1.1: no version information available (required by ./impalad)
./impalad: /impala/lib64/libssl.so.1.1: no version information available (required by ./impalad)
./impalad: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.23' not found (required by ./impalad)
./impalad: /impala/lib64/libsasl2.so.2: no version information available (required by ./impalad)
```

Here As per my understanding the message shows that it requires GLIBC 2.27 version. but the libc.so.6 is of version 2.17 which is by default present in linux and latest as per centos 7.

Main concern is Centos 7 also has 2.17 version but there it is working and in rhel7 it is not working.

Any help is appreciated....
Thanks In Advance....

Comment: CentOS 7 packages are built from the same SRPMs that RHEL 7 packages are built from.  The two are as compatible as operating systems can be, and both are enterprise-class systems, focusing on long-term stability over having the most recent features, so even the latest updates do not change the version of glibc.

Comment: Possible explanations of the observed behavior include, but are not limited to: (i) your'e actually building on CentOS [Stream] 8, not 7. Version 8 provides glibc 2.28.  (ii) Impala's "buildall" script built a more recent glibc for it and its dependencies to use, and which you have not copied to the RHEL server.

Comment: @JohnBollinger my system is centos 7 only i again verified. I tried to find glibc.so.6 in whole linux but only found one copy in /usr/lib64. Question arise is if impala is using glibc of upgraded version why it is not giving error in Centos 7.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I had tried copying same glibc.so.6 file to development server and put it in dedicated folder and added it it LD_LIBRARY_PATH still it was giving error.  Is there any other file which need to copied for that libraries meta data serving purpose.

Comment: It is not plausible that the same build of Impala and its bundled dependencies runs successfully on one glibc-2.17 system, using the system libc of that machine, but fails with libc-version errors on another such machine.  Furthermore, you appear to have some additional, unrelated dependency problems with the libraries bundled with Impala.  I don't know what happened here, but if your machines are matched as you say they are, then whatever you are trying to run on RHEL is not the same thing you are running successfully on CentOS 7.

Comment: Okay @JohnBollinger Thanks for valuable input will build it another time and will try again.

Comment: Ok, but it seems more likely to me that the problem is with transferring the built software to the RHEL machine, not with the build.  At least some of the components that you are running on CentOS are different from the ones you are trying to on RHEL.  Your guess would be much better than mine as to how that might have happened.